# Is it right to say, a static charge (not moving) can't not feel magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, charge

how far this statement is correct? it takes a moving charge to produce a magnetic field, and it takes another moving electric charge to "feel" it. how far this statement is correct?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at Jefimenko's formulation of Maxwell's equation, the two sources of a magnetic field at $(\vec r, t)$ are:

$$\frac{\vec r-\vec r'}{|\vec r-\vec r'|^3}\times \vec J(\vec r', t_r)$$

$$\frac{\vec r-\vec r'}{|\vec r-\vec r'|^2}\times \frac 1 c \frac{\partial J(\vec r', t_r)}{\partial t}$$

with the retard time being $t_r = r-\frac{|\vec r-\vec r'|}c$.

So it's current and changing current on the past light cone. (Of course, current is moving charge).

The Lorentz force law says:

$$ \vec F = q(\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B) $$

so yes: a charge needs to move to 'feel' a magnetic field.

On the other hand, most charges we work with have a magnetic dipole moment, which 'feel' an aligning torque when stationary....but that's technically more than just a charge. I suppose charged pions are safe.

Answer (score 0):

A charge has a permanent magnetic dipole beside its electric charge. An electrons is a tiny magnet. So it is without any doubt that a charge will be aligned by an external magnetic field.